# Setting a column based on count distinct of the field

Tags: sql, hive

Is this possible where you want to count a field, and if the count distinct field is = 1, then you use the column but if the count distinct is > 1 you set it to, "not identifiable.

Table looks like this

```
store furniture        furniture_model
A     ikea         round
A     ikea         square
B     ikea         round
C     ikea         square
```

Results

```
A     ikea         no model wrong data
B     ikea         round
C     ikea         square
```

Using

```
SELECT ID, furniture,
 CASE
       WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT furniture_model) > 1 THEN 'Non Identified Old Model'
       ELSE furniture_model
 END old_model
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use:

```
select store, table,
       (case when min(table_model) = max(table_model) then min(table_model)
             else 'Non Identified Old Model'
        end)
from t
group by store, table;
```

Note that `table` is a really bad name for a column name.  Even if it is allowed, it is a SQL keyword.  Even worse, it means something in the database world -- and that something is not "column".

Comment: Looks like the UDAF is not supported in hive version I am using yet

Comment: What is UDAF?  This is standard SQL -- well, except for the use of `table` s a column name.

Comment: Thank you. Table was a bad example column name.  Was thinking of a furniture as an ex to display models of furniture.